# problem initialization order in buffer overflow problem

Tags: c, gcc, stack, buffer-overflow

First thing, this is a homework problem. I am not sure if it is ok but don't post anything about how to change the int value.

My question is if I have the order of

```
int set_me = 0;
char buf[15];
```

switch to

```
char buf[15];
int set_me = 0;
```

It still will change the integer by overflow the char array. I use `gcc -m32 -o buffer  -O0 -fno-stack-protector buffer.c` to compile the file. I guess `-O0` let gcc not to optimize the stack, so the int an char[] should be in order as they are in the c code. Original code did something in the if condition not showing there.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        if(argc != 2)

        {

                printf("usage:\n%s string\n", argv[0]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        int set_me = 0;
        char buf[15];

        if(set_me == 1111222){}
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is free to allocate the variables wherever it wishes. There is no guarantee the change in the order in the code will have any impact on the generated binary.

Comment: The buffer isn't touched by anything. How is it supposed to be attacked?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. (Or what the purpose of this code snippet is.)

Comment: Part of the original code isn't showing here. char buf[15] will be changed to a argv[]. and there is call to start a shell inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of variables on the stack is implementation dependent.

Just because variables are defined in a certain order in code doesn't mean they'll be in the same order in the compiled program.  Adding more variables of varying types may or may not change the ordering, as can changing the optimization settings.

If you're testing a buffer overflow, you'll need to play around with the variable declarations until you get the layout you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the order of your declarations can in no way predict the order of allocation on the stack, even without optimizations. It is completely implementation dependent.

However, if you do overflow your 'buf', you will write to higher and higher addresses, but the stack (generally) grows downwards.

So while nothing can be determined about overwriting other variables within your stack frame, you can be sure that with a sufficiently large buffer overflow you will destroy the stack above main(), which among other things contains the return address of whatever called main(), and that will crash your program in one way or another. Best to keep the stack protector enabled since a detected stack smashing is a relatively clean exit from your broken program.

An uncontrolled overflow can lead to all sorts of strange behaviour, especially if the overwritten return address points to some executable code. This is a typical setup for overflow attacks.

> My question is if I have the order of

```
int set_me = 0;
char buf[15];
```

switch to

```
char buf[15];
int set_me = 0;
```

It still will change the integer by overflow the char array. I use gcc -m32 -o buffer  -O0 -fno-stack-protector buffer.c to compile the file. I guess -O0 let gcc not to optimize the stack, so the int an char[] should be in order as they are in the c code. Original code did something in the if condition not showing there. <